Country of chargeability as an adoptee
I am a Canadian citizen who was born in China and adopted at the age of one. My adoptive parents' country of birth is Japan. Can I use Japan as my country of chargeability ("Just Passing Through" Exception) when applying for a green card (not DV lottery)? Is there an age limit/requirement for the applicant? Lastly, do my parents need to apply for a green card as well for this to work?

Cross-posted to Law.SE: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/103428/cross-chargeability-as-an-adoptee


Can I use Japan as my country of chargeability ("Just Passing Through"
Exception) when applying for a green card (not DV lottery)?

I don't know the answer to this. The text of the law in INA 202(b)(4) (8 USC 1152(b)(4)) says:

(b) [...] For the purposes of this chapter the foreign state to which
an immigrant is chargeable shall be determined by birth within such
foreign state except that
(4) an alien born within any foreign state in which neither of his
parents was born and in which neither of his parents had a residence
at the time of such alien's birth may be charged to the foreign state
of either parent.

The text of the regulations in 22 CFR 42.12(e) says:

An alien who was born in a foreign state, as defined in § 40.1, in
which neither parent was born, and in which neither parent had a
residence at the time of the applicant's birth, may be charged to the
foreign state of either parent as provided in INA 202(b)(4). The
parents of such an alien are not considered as having acquired a
residence within the meaning of INA 202(b)(4), if, at the time of the
alien's birth within the foreign state, the parents were visiting
temporarily or were stationed there in connection with the business or
profession and under orders or instructions of an employer, principal,
or superior authority foreign to such foreign state.

In both cases, if "parent" could be interpreted as your adoptive parent, then I guess you could use your adoptive parents' country of chargeability (Japan), since presumably neither of them were residing in China at the time of your birth. Usually, after an adoption, the terms "parent" and "child" in the law refer to the adoptive parent and child, so that could support this interpretation. On the other hand, this section doesn't really make much sense if applied to adoptive parents, since it makes little sense to hinge on what an adoptive parent was doing at the time you were born, potentially many years before they even knew of your existence. I haven't seen any official sources that address this particular situation.

Is there an age limit/requirement for the applicant?

No

Lastly, do my parents need to apply for a green card as well for this
to work?

No.
Now, if your parent did immigrate in a category that allows derivative beneficiaries, and you were unmarried and under 21, you could immigrate as their derivative beneficiary, in which case you would be able to use the principal beneficiary's country of chargeability. But this is a separate provision from the ability to use a parent's country of chargeability based on the parents not being citizens or residents of your country of birth.
